# How to cancel or remove echo/repeated sound with AVAudioEngine?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am using the AVAudioEngine for audio streaming. But when I speak any word into the mic, it repeats multiple times, just like echo effect. I want when I speak, it sounds only one time, not multiple times. I want to cancel the echo or extra noise.

How can I achieve this?

```
var peerAudioEngine: AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine() 
var peerAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode() 
var peerInput: AVAudioInputNode? 
var peerInputFormat: AVAudioFormat? 

func setUpAVPlayer() { 
    self.peerInput = self.peerAudioEngine.inputNode 
    self.peerAudioEngine.attach(self.peerAudioPlayer) 
    self.peerInputFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: false) 
    self.peerAudioEngine.connect(self.peerAudioPlayer, to: self.peerAudioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: self.peerInputFormat) 

    print("\(#file) > \(#function) > peerInputFormat = \(self.peerInputFormat.debugDescription)") 
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code about what have you done so far.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Please check my code

Comment: Are you recording something in an environment that creates echo?

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Yes, I am recording using AVaudioEngine but when I send  it and play it creates echo or repeating voice

Comment: I meant are your recording in an empty big room which would create echo while recording? So that might be the actual issue.

Comment: no.. echo create every time by default. Is there any property to cancel the echo?@ParasGorasiya

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @VladimirPrigarin Yes, but currently i am not working

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be able to solve your issue by this code

```
var reverbNode = AVAudioUnitReverb()
reverbNode.loadFactoryPreset( AVAudioUnitReverbPreset.Cathedral)
reverbNode.wetDryMix = 60
// Attach the audio effect node corresponding to the user selected effect
peerAudioEngine.attachNode(reverbNode)
```

Also you may want to consider other approach in which you can mute your mic after you speak and that you have to detect manually when your `peerAudioEngine` doesnt receive any input audio you mute it.

This will completely eliminates echo from your speech.

For more info you can visit
http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/502

Comment: Have you any other solution?